# How many witnesses are required to a tenancy contract in England?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, witnesses

We need to get a new AST rental contract between ourselves and existing tenants. Given the current rules on minimising contact and travel in the UK we'd like to minimise how many people are involved.

Many contract templates have different witness requirements, what legally what is actually required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no legal requirement for an Assured Shorthold Tenancy agreement in England and Wales to be witnessed.

Signatories to the agreement are legally free to have it witnessed.

Some people may prefer it to be witnessed.